# SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<' - Jquery 1.10.2

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, gridview, twitter-bootstrap-3

Getting SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<' in jquery
jquery-1.10.2.min
bootstrap 3.
Can anyone let me know what I am missing over here?

[image]

Comment: Have you closed your <!DOCTYPE html>? The screenshot looks like that could be the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first line of that particular console log shows that it is responding with

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC ...

This is usually the case when a 404 error page is returned instead of the file its self because the file location was incorrect.

Comment: but when i click on the link in console itself, it show me jquery min file

Comment: @ajayp perhaps there's an issue with a router or something to some effect. Nonetheless, HTML is only returned when requesting a javascript file is an HTML page is displayed instead of the JS, it isn't an arbitrary thing. Check, check and double check!

Answer (score 0):

Today I got that exact error:

SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'  jquery-1.11.0.min.js:1 
as well as 
ReferenceError: $ is not defined in my js file.

- I tried ping'ing code.jquery.com and it didn't get through.
- I checked out www.isitdownrightnow.com with the https://code.jquery.com and saw that it was up.
- I put https://code.jquery.com in my browser and it consistently timed out.
- I cleared my cookies and browser history and restarted my browser and still, I was timing out.
- I was able to connect to other websites.  Odd.
- I contacted my friend in another part of the country and he was able to connect.

Finally I rebooted my machine, cleared my browser history, cache and cookies once again, and I'm back on track.

Muph!  Good luck to you.

Answer (score 0):

I've been grappling with this for a while now, tried almost everything with bundling and master page markup, and I thought for sure it was realted to `FriendlyUrls`.

I just realized I hadn't added `clientIDMode` to the web.config. When I did, the `SyntaxError` was fixed, along with some other stuff.

```
<pages clientIDMode="Static">
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to execute the html file which includes the javascript source, in the server, just enter the name of the folder which contains the executable html file. Do not enter the html file itself.
For ex. if you are currently in folder 'A' and the html file is in subfolder 'B', just enter command as (using live server) below:

live-server B\